# C++ How to combine two signed 8 Bit numbers to a 16 Bit short? Unexplainable results

Tags: c++, byte, signed, short

I need to combine two signed 8 Bit _int8 values to a signed short (16 Bit) value. It is important that the sign is not lost.

My code is:

```
 unsigned short lsb = -13;
 unsigned short msb = 1;
 short combined = (msb << 8 )| lsb;
```

The result I get is `-13`. However, I expect it to be `499`.

For the following examples, I get the correct results with the same code:

```
msb = -1; lsb = -6; combined = -6;
msb = 1; lsb = 89; combined = 345; 
msb = -1; lsb = 13; combined = -243;
```

However, `msb = 1; lsb = -84; combined = -84;` where I would expect `428`.

It seems that if the lsb is negative and the msb is positive, something goes wrong!
What is wrong with my code? How does the computer get to these unexpected results (Win7, 64 Bit and VS2008 C++)?

Comment: numbers are represented in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement . this is what happens when you OR 2 2's complement numbers. don't.

Comment: Why are your "signed 8-bit values" stored in an `unsigned short`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your lsb in this case contains 0xfff3.  When you OR it with 1 << 8 nothing changes because there is already a 1 in that bit position.

Try `short combined = (msb << 8 ) | (lsb & 0xff);`

Answer (score 8):

Or using a union:

```
#include <iostream>

union Combine
{
    short target;
    char dest[ sizeof( short ) ];
};

int main()
{
    Combine cc;
    cc.dest[0] = -13, cc.dest[1] = 1;
    std::cout << cc.target << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Not advisable to use unions due to portability issues.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that `lsb` is being automatically sign-extended to 16 bits. I notice you only have a problem when it is negative and msb is positive, and that is what you would expect to happen given the way you're using the or operator. Although, you're clearly doing something very strange here. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks Dan! The data in the file I read in are stored as 8Bit signed integers with always the LSB first followed by the MSB. To use these data I need to combine them into a 16 Bit signed short. I read in the file as char and convert to _int8. How to do this correctly?

Comment: @Natalie: I'm afraid I don't think what you say makes sense. How do individual bytes of a multi-byte integer representation even *have* a notion of "sign"? Why don't you just read the two bytes into a signed short an be done with it?

Comment: Sorry, I have not invented this file format. I have to read in the whole file as char because the file contains also ASCII parts and not all data in the file have to be combined into shorts. I need first to separate the data to get those stored as 8 Bit signed int.

Answer (score 2):

Raisonanse C complier for STM8 (and, possibly, many other compilers) generates ugly code for classic C code when writing  16-bit variables into 8-bit hardware registers.
Note - STM8 is big-endian, for little-endian CPUs code must be slightly modified. Read/Write byte order is important too.

So, standard C code piece:

```
 unsigned int ch1Sum;
...
     TIM5_CCR1H = ch1Sum >> 8; 
     TIM5_CCR1L = ch1Sum;
```

Is being compiled to:

```
;TIM5_CCR1H = ch1Sum >> 8; 
         LDW   X,ch1Sum 
         CLR   A 
         RRWA  X,A 
         LD    A,XL 
         LD    TIM5_CCR1,A 
;TIM5_CCR1L = ch1Sum; 
         MOV   TIM5_CCR1+1,ch1Sum+1
```

Too long, too slow.

My version:

```
     unsigned int ch1Sum;
...
     TIM5_CCR1H = ((u8*)&ch1Sum)[0];
     TIM5_CCR1L = ch1Sum;
```

That is compiled into adequate two MOVes

```
;TIM5_CCR1H = ((u8*)&ch1Sum)[0]; 
       MOV   TIM5_CCR1,ch1Sum 
;TIM5_CCR1L = ch1Sum;
       MOV   TIM5_CCR1+1,ch1Sum+1
```

Opposite direction:

```
    unsigned int uSonicRange;
...
      ((unsigned char *)&uSonicRange)[0] = TIM1_CCR2H;
      ((unsigned char *)&uSonicRange)[1] = TIM1_CCR2L;
```

instead of

```
    unsigned int uSonicRange;
...
      uSonicRange = TIM1_CCR2H << 8;
      uSonicRange |= TIM1_CCR2L;
```

Answer (score 2):

Some things you should know about the datatypes (*un*)*signed* *short* and *char*:

*char* is an 8-bit value, thats what you where looking for for *lsb* and *msb*. *short* is 16 bits in length.

You should also not store *signed* values in *unsigned* ones execpt you know what you are doing.

You can take a look at [the two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). It describes the representation of negative values (for integers, not for floating-point values) in C/C++ and many other programming languages.

There are multiple versions of making your own two's complement:

```
int a;
// setting a
a = -a;     // Clean version. Easier to understand and read. Use this one.
a = (~a)+1; // The arithmetical version. Does the same, but takes more steps.
// Don't use the last one unless you need it!
// It can be 'optimized away' by the compiler.
```

---

[stdint.h (with inttypes.h)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) is more for the purpose of having exact lengths for your variable. If you really need a variable to have a specific byte-length you should use that (here you need it).

You should everythime use datatypes which fit your needs the best. Your code should therefore look like this:

```
signed char  lsb; // signed 8-bit value
signed char  msb; // signed 8-bit value
signed short combined = msb << 8  |  (lsb & 0xFF); // signed 16-bit value
```

or like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int8_t lsb; // signed 8-bit value
int8_t msb; // signed 8-bit value
int_16_t combined = msb << 8  |  (lsb & 0xFF); // signed 16-bit value
```

For the last one the compiler will use signed 8/16-bit values everytime regardless what length *int* has on your platform. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) got some nice explanation of the *int8_t* and *int16_t* datatypes (and all the other datatypes).

btw: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is useful for looking up the [ANSI C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) standards and other things that are worth to know about C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote, that you need to combine two 8-bit values. Why you're using `unsigned short` then?
As `Dan` already said, `lsb` automatically extended to 16 bits. Try the following code:

```
uint8_t lsb = -13;
uint8_t msb = 1;
int16_t combined = (msb << 8) | lsb;
```

This gives you the expected result: `499`.

Comment: I tried to use uint8_t but my compiler does not know this type and #include <stdint.h> results in no such file or directory error. Maybe a VS2008 problem? Thanks!

Comment: For VS use `unsigned __int8` and `__int16` types.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want:

```
msb: 1, lsb: -13, combined: 499
msb: -6, lsb: -1, combined: -1281
msb: 1, lsb: 89, combined: 345
msb: -1, lsb: 13, combined: -243
msb: 1, lsb: -84, combined: 428
```

Use this:

```
short combine(unsigned char msb, unsigned char lsb) {
    return (msb<<8u)|lsb;
}
```

I don't understand why you would want msb -6 and lsb -1 to generate -6 though.

Comment: You are right! Sorry, I mixed up msb and lsb for this example and corrected it in my post. Thanks!